# Turning XY data into polygon, and then sorting them clockwise

Tags: matlab, math, functional-programming, geometry

I got data set (formed by sum of sub-sets, hence its unsorted) and Id like to turn it into polygon.

Is there a simple Matlab procedure that sorts/turns data set into polygon? The data form outline of a polygon, BUT they are NOT in correct order:
[image]

(to the left). The polygon must consist of ALL the points, and the lines CANT intersect.

Sadly the polygon is NOT convex, so `convhull` wont work :C

Thanks for any ideas, Ben

EDIT: heres a little example of what I need to do - I need to convert blue polygon into red one, so there are no intersections.

```
x1 = [0,     1,     2,     1,     2,     0]
x2 = [0,     1,     2,     2,     1,     0]
y1 = [2,     1,     3,     3,     1,     2]
y2 = [2,     1,     1,     3,     3,     2]

plot(x1,y1,'b-*')
axis([0,3,0,4])
pause
hold on, plot(x2,y2,'r-o')
```

EDIT 2: Ive finally managed to get rid of excess data, so here's the actual data Im trying to fit (blue points), data fit by matlab when using convhull to the left, and how its SUPPOSED to look, edited with green lines - to the right.

Ive tried looking for Hamiltonian path in Matlab but didnt find any direct commands, is there one for it?
[image]
And here's the data:

```
data1=[19.4500010000000 50500000;19.4500010000000 52810000;19.4500010000000 55200000;19.4599990000000 55200000;19.6900010000000 48800000;19.7910002000000 55200000;19.8560000000000 55200000;20.0100000000000 55200000;20.1500000000000 55200000;26.8099990000000 54700000;26.8099990000000 54700000;27.8300000000000 54500000;27.8300000000000 54500000;27.8300000000000 54500000;25.4047236012803 43066163.6552646;38.2799990000000 8420000;38.2799990000000 8420000;38.2799990000000 8420000;36.4199980000000 5270000;36.4199980000000 5270000;36.4199980000000 5270000;36.4199980000000 5270000;49.1845567757586 1577538.50621129;47.4100000000000 926524;47.4100000000000 926524;47.4100000000000 926524.000000004;47.4100000000000 926524;61.1736702657022 365441.704934877;58.3499980000000 230682;58.3499980000000 230682;71.8983466422650 108263.586243626;69.5500030000000 74543.3000000000;79.6100010000000 30424.7000000000;79.7029992000000 30424.7000000000;79.7699970000000 30424.7000000000;83.6800000000000 31281.3000000000;83.6800000000000 31693.1300000000;83.6800000000000 32131.1000000000]
c1=[1;5;19;24;29;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;12;11;9;8;7;6;4;3;2;1]
semilogy(data1(:,1),data1(:,2),'-*b')
hold on, semilogy(data1(c1,1),data1(c1,2),'r')
```

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow generally should contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34898713/edit) your question to ensure that the code in your question is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more).

Comment: I was hoping my general explanation would sufice for now, as I am still working on obtaining said data set, but Ill add a small example to use for now.

Comment: It is not clear how you define the polygon, think about the example `[0 0;0 1;1 0;-1 0;0 -1]`. Which is the right order? When go via the center point?

Comment: Maybe the shortest hamiltonian path is what you want?

Comment: I was so stuck on solving this geometrically I didnt think about graphs - basically what I need to do is connect data points that form outline of a polygon into single shape, that can concave, but with no intersections, so hamiltonian path just might work - thanks for the idea.

Comment: You need to be more specific with at least few tricky examples you will face - the example you give is a simple one and will work with a variety of methods.

Comment: I think there is no general solution. There are multiple polygons possible from a given unordered point set.

Comment: Even after considering a) all points must be used b) lines forming the polygon cant intersect?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the points according to the angle with regard to the center of the points, as follows:

```
%Generate random example
n = 10;
x = rand(1,n);
y = rand(1,n);
%Find the order of the points
[~,porder] = sort(atan2(y-mean(y),x-mean(x)));
xsort = x(porder);
ysort = y(porder);
%Plot polygon
scatter(x,y);
hold on;
plot([xsort,xsort(1)],[ysort,ysort(1)]);
```

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work given that the polygon can be concave.

Comment: @Suever According to the formulation of the question, and the drawn example, the polygon is allowed to be concave, just not intersect itself.

Comment: @Suever Yes, that is a concave polygon possible made by my method. It still satisfies the requirements in the question statement.

Comment: That's exactly the point, that's NOT what your code produces. That was my input polygon. I have attached the one that your code generates http://imgur.com/vvtFN2O

Comment: Input data (ordered) was: `[0.1576,0.1419; 0.9706,0.4218; 0.9572,0.9157; 0.3385, 0.4974; 0.4854,0.7922;0.7094,1.0096;0.1472,1.0137]`

Comment: The truth of the matter is that there is no unique solution, but using angles like you have, at least in my experience where we are dealing with irregular shapes, rarely yields the result I want.

Comment: @Suever Yes I realize that there is no unique solution. My method just gives one solution. If you want a specific solution, you need to specify which criteria make one solution better than another!

Comment: Im not sure how to specify it more precisely - basically I need convex hull of entire thing, but without unused nodes and crossing lines - does that make sense? :D

Comment: @Benjikshoo: Take a look at the two possible solutions Suever linked, is there any to prefer? If yes why? If no just take this answer.

Comment: @Benjikshoo you cannot specify it more precisly because there is no unique solution to your task.

Comment: IN FACT I found a matlab function called 'boundary', and according to documentation it should do EXACTLY what I need - kinda like convhull but with ability to shrink more to reach points convhull doesnt - but for shame its introduced in matlab 2014B, and my Matlab doesnt have it :C Could anybody run it on the data set ive provided in original post and see what the results are similar to desired? Running log10 on Y data might be needed to achieve reasonable weights for the entire data set.

Comment: @Benjikshoo The `boundry` function does not include all points in the polygon, even if you set the shrink factor to 0, At least not in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I have suggestion although I'm not 100% sure it will work for all possible collection of points.

Step1 : Start with a convex hull of the points and generate a polygon.

Step2 : Collect all the points which are not part of the convex hull.

Step3 : Then determine the shortest distance for each point to any segment of the convex hull polygon.

Step4: Pick the point with the smallest distance and split the segment that it is closest to, to pass through this point.

Step5: Repeat from step 2 until all points are included.

Comment: That could work, but it sounds like a lot of coding... gonna ask around, see if anybody of my friends has access to 2014b so I can try using 'boundary' function, that should do it with just one command... Thanks anyway :]